# Query problem

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

When I execute this query:

```
Dim Var
Var = ("select max(Autonumber) from tblAutonumber")
DoCmd.RunSQL (Var)
```

I am getting the value of var as `"select max(Autonumber) from tblAutonumber"` instead of the maximum value I am looking for.

#### Code:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Enter()
DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblAutonumber (Dummy)values ('DummyValue')")

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strMaxNum As String
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "select max(Autonumber) as maxNum from tblAutonumber"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

 rst.MoveFirst
 strMaxNum = rst!maxNum
'Dim Var As Variant
'Var = "select max(Autonumber) from tblAutonumber"
'DoCmd.RunSQL (Var)
txtAutoNumber.Value = strSQL
DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tbltesting (Empid,TestScenario,owner,event,version,expresult,variation,status,homestore)values ('" & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & Me.txtTestScenario.Value & "','" & Me.txtOwner.Value & "','" & Me.txtEvent.Value & "', '" & Me.txtVersion.Value & "','" & Me.txtExpectedResult.Value & "', '" & Me.txtVariation.Value & "', '" & Me.txtStatus.Value & "','" & Me.txtHomeStore.Value & "')")
'DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tblContract(testid)select max(testid) FROM tbltesting")
 DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tblContract (Empid,testid,Start1,Finish1,Store1,Start2,Finish2,Store2 )values ('" & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" & Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "')")
 'DoCmd.RunSQL = "INSERT INTO tblContract (Empid,testid, Start1, Finish1, Store1, Start2, Finish2, Store2)  SELECT " & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "', MAX(testid), '" & Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "' " & "FROM tbltesting'"
'DoCmd.RunSQL = "INSERT INTO tblContract (Empid,testid, Start1, Finish1, Store1, Start2, Finish2, Store2)  SELECT " & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "', MAX(testid), '" & Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "' " & "FROM tbltesting'"
End Sub
```

Comment: The value of Var should be the string, "select max(Autonumber) from tblAutonumber"
strMaxNum will equal the value as returned from the query. 
I have tested this on my sample database and it works, (after adding the semicolon, and I am not doing any of the insert statements).  Try testing the select, without the inserts, assuming there is data in tblAutonumber and Autonumber is a valid field name.

Comment: could you please repost my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to accomplish you might want to just use the DMAX Domain Aggregate Function which will return the max expression (i.e. column) for a given domain (i.e. table). Here is an example:

```
  Dim lastAutonumber As Long
  lastAutonumber = DMax("Autonumber", "tblAutonumber")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rich commented:

```
Dim Var 
Var = "select max(Autonumber) from tblAutonumber"
DoCmd.RunSQL (Var)
```

Comment: No Joy 

This is the value now 

"select max(Autonumber) from tblAutonumber"

Answer (score 0):

Using the Access UI:

```
Dim Var As Long
var = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("select max(Autonumber) from tblAutonumber;")(0)
```

Comment: To unpack that a bit, you're returning the value of index number 0 of the fields collection of the returned recordset object. I had to ponder this one for a bit to figure out why it worked. Dunno why in an Access context DMax() would not be the obvious solution, though.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the SQL code from the question -- I didn't seek to re-write the query ;) I read that the domain functions should be avoided on performance grounds (MSDN optimization article, now disappeared) but I personally avoid them on portability grounds i.e. the SELECT MAX(... type vanilla SQL will run against any SQL product.